# Something wrong in my coding in java with numbers and strings

Tags: java, if-statement, error-handling, integer, double

I tried to develop a java program using netbeans in which a GUI accepts subject marks from five text fields and displays the total marks, percentage and the grade in their respective text fields.
The problem is I am getting errors while executing the GUI. I tried replacing int with double to hold decimal values of percentage but that didn't help. I am unable to find any errors and since I am a beginner i am unable to understand the errors given in the monitor by my netbeans. Please help.

```
ERRORS: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "           34"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at NewJFrame.submit_buttonActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:173)
    at NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:4)
    at NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:60)
```

Here's the coding I've done.

```
        int sub1_ = Integer.parseInt(sub1.getText());
    int sub2_ = Integer.parseInt(sub2.getText());
    int sub3_ = Integer.parseInt(sub3.getText());
    int sub4_ = Integer.parseInt(sub4.getText());
    int sub5_ = Integer.parseInt(sub5.getText());

    // Here each subject holds a max. of 100 marks.

    int a = sub1_+sub2_+sub3_+sub4_+sub5_;
    total_marks.setText(""+a);

    // Since each subject holds a max. of 100 marks, the total marks of five subjects sums up to 500.

    int b = (a/500)*100;
    percentage.setText(b+"%");

    if(b<=100&&b>=91)
    {grade.setText("A1");}

    else if(b<=90&&b>=81)
    {grade.setText("A2");}

    else if(b<=80&&b>=71)
    {grade.setText("B1");}

    else if(b<=70&&b>=61)
    {grade.setText("B2");}

    else if(b<=60&&b>=51)
    {grade.setText("C1");}

    else if(b<=50&&b>=35)
    {grade.setText("C2");}

    else if(b<=34&&b>=0)
    {grade.setText("D");}

    else {grade.setText("");}
```

Comment: Note: if it is not `b>=91` then you know `b<=90` must be true so you don't need to check for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 34"`

Trim the `String` of whitespace before using the parse methods.

```
try {

    int sub1_ = Integer.parseInt(sub1.getText().trim());
    int sub2_ = Integer.parseInt(sub2.getText().trim());
    int sub3_ = Integer.parseInt(sub3.getText().trim());
    int sub4_ = Integer.parseInt(sub4.getText().trim());
    int sub5_ = Integer.parseInt(sub5.getText().trim());

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    // invalid input

}
```

Answer (score 2):

At some point you are trying to parse the integer " 34", the leading space is a problem for the parsing method.

You should either make sure your integer has no whitespace when you create it, or use the trim() function to remove leading and trailing whitespace,

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the issues already reported, the line `int b = (a/500)*100;` should be `int b = (a * 100) / 500;` or, simpler, `int b = a/5;`. The division by 500 rounds down to an integer, so if `a` is less than 500 the result is zero.

Comment: Would I be wrong in saying that he can cast the `a` value to a `float` during assignment?   `int b = ((float) a / 500f) * 100f`.

Comment: @mrres1 That is an alternative, though you would need a cast to int. However, in some cases of float divide followed by cast to int rounding error can cause an answer one smaller than the correct answer. I don't know whether that can happen in this case, but why risk it unnecessarily?

Comment: There is no rounding when casting to an integer, the number is truncated.  For example, `int a = (int) 1.999f;` will truncate everything after the decimal `.`  So `a == 1`.

Comment: He could do, `int b = Math.round(((float) a / 500f) * 100f);`

Comment: @mrres1 I meant division rounding error leading to a number slightly less than the real number arithmetic result, which on truncation goes to the next integer down. Yes, if you really, really want to use floating point you could, but why do so when there is a much simpler integer arithmetic expression that does the job?

Comment: I agree, there is a much more efficient way.  I just do not feel that you've provided an answer, but a remark or comment about the code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the question asked, there is a way to reduce the clutter in your code.

For example, you have multiple if-statements that all do the same thing, but with different numbers.
In this case, you can just create a function.

```
private boolean inRangeOf(int value, int max, int min) {

    return value <= max && value >= min;

}
```

You can then replace your conditions with calls to `inRangeOf(x, a, b)`

```
if( inRangeOf(b, 100, 91) ) {

    grade.setText("A1");

}

else if( inRangeOf(b, 90, 81) ) {

    grade.setText("A2");

}

else if( inRangeOf(b, 80, 71) ) {

    grade.setText("B1");

}
```